# search in reactjs only showing for the last condition but not getting results for above lines

Tags: reactjs, search

this is my search handler and iam only able to get results for the last one

```
handleSearch = (event) => {
const searchWord = event.target.value;
const newFilter = this.state.data.filter((value) => {
  return (
    value.programName.toLowerCase().includes(searchWord.toLowerCase()),//not working
    value.endTime.toLowerCase().includes(searchWord.toLowerCase()),//not working
    value.description.toLowerCase().includes(searchWord.toLowerCase()) //only getting search related to this line
  )
});
this.setState({
  data1: newFilter,
});
```

};

Comment: What do you mean not working ? Please elaborate ? Is it an error ? Then explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) expression.

The **comma operator** (`,`) evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

I think you meant to return a boolean expression. Use logical AND (`&&`) if you want all conditions to be true, or logical OR (`||`) if only at least one condition to be true.

```
const newFilter = this.state.data.filter((value) => {
  return value.programName.toLowerCase().includes(searchWord.toLowerCase())
    && value.endTime.toLowerCase().includes(searchWord.toLowerCase())
    && value.description.toLowerCase().includes(searchWord.toLowerCase());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you are returning several values separated by commas, in which case, only the last one will be returned. [More about comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)